# NGINX count requests per second

Tags: c, nginx

I'm developing an anti application-layer attack module for NGINX and I have to count the request per second (every second). The idea is to make an auto detector of attacks which turns the filtering on when there is an increase in the request rate.

At this time this is happening with the help of a shell script which is reading the access log every second and is calculating the request rate. The problem is that this isn't very performance effective.

If you have an idea on how can I achieve this, please, share your thoughts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpLimitReqModule:

```
http {
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=1r/s;

...

server {

    ...

    location /search/ {
        limit_req   zone=one  burst=5;
    }
```

reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this would help me much. This module limits the requests per user.... and I don't want that.
 
I need to count the requests per second and I want to add this to my module (nginx must be as lightweight as possible) (may be some incremented variable which is flushed every second) but what is the method to catch those requests so I can increment the variable?

Thanks.

Comment: I would go with above proposal. You want to drop all traffic which comes from specific IP addresses rather than lock down your service! Second approach is to use fail2ban like in this solution https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban/

Answer (score -2):

Use `tail -f -s` on access_log. It's pretty effective.